# requirejs + IE8: undefined object is null or not an object

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, undefined, requirejs

I'm getting an error only in IE having to do with the require.js plugin.

I have the following code in require.js (line 1061):

```
 if (plugin.normalize) {
```

IE 8 is returning this error:

> Message: 'normalize' is null or not an object
>
> Line: 1061
>   Char: 25

I've checked the debugger and the plugin object exists, normalize is undefined.  In javascript, this should evaluate as "false", and fail the if-condition.  However, for some reason IE is throwing this error instead and not letting my page load correctly.  Does anyone know why this is happening?

Ironically, if I change line 1061 to this:

```
if (plugin.normalize !== undefined && plugin.normalize !== null && plugin.normalize !== false) {
```

Then IE8 runs the code successfully...the problem is, this should be equivalent code, and I can't be altering third-party packages like require.js just to avoid IE bugs like this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue that I fixed by making sure that I had no trailing comas and that my paths were good.

More details here: https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/299

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, it comes if there are some file not found error (404), make sure the path provided for scripts are correct,(fallback path seems to be not working in IE8), after fixing paths it solved.